# UITableView's contentOffset keep changing itself

Tags: iphone, keyboard, tableview, edit

**UPDATED**: Scroll down for updated.

I have a UITableView which cells contain few UITextView(s). When user start editing text and keyboard show up, I resize TableView's frame and scroll editing cell to visible with method scrollToRowAtIndexPath::: of UITableView. All this work perfectly until user actually start typing. Problem is, every time the keyboard's key was hit, the y value of contentOffset property of UITableView change itself.

I try to log this for every keys stroke

```
NSLog(@"%1.2f, %1.2f, %1.2f, %1.2f", 
          self.table.contentSize.width, 
          self.table.contentSize.height, 
          self.table.contentOffset.x, 
          self.table.contentOffset.y);
```

And this is the result

```
2011-03-17 00:13:05.380 ...[6243:207] 320.00, 355.00, 0.00, 8.00
2011-03-17 00:13:06.138 ...[6243:207] 320.00, 355.00, 0.00, 13.00
2011-03-17 00:13:06.848 ...[6243:207] 320.00, 355.00, 0.00, 8.00
2011-03-17 00:13:07.578 ...[6243:207] 320.00, 355.00, 0.00, 13.00
2011-03-17 00:13:08.377 ...[6243:207] 320.00, 355.00, 0.00, 8.00
```

As you can see, the contentOffset.y just keep changing all the time, and that makes TableView jump up and down for every key stroke. There's no where in my code that change TableView's contentOffset value, or at least not explicitly. Anyone have any idea what happen?

Here's the code I use to adjust TableView size when show/hide keyboard

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (keyboardAlreadyShow) // in case user jump from one TextView to another
        return;

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* aValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    CGRect keyboardRect = [aValue CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

    CGFloat keyboardTop = keyboardRect.origin.y;
    CGRect newFrame = self.view.bounds;
    newFrame.origin.x = self.table.frame.origin.x;
    newFrame.size.width = self.table.frame.size.width;
    newFrame.size.height = keyboardTop;

    NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration 
                     animations:^{
                         self.table.frame = newFrame;
                     }];

    NSIndexPath *index = [table indexPathForCell:editingCell];
    [self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:index atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];

    keyboardAlreadyShow = YES;

}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification 
{   
    CGRect newFrame;
    newFrame.origin.y = self.table.frame.origin.y;
    newFrame.origin.x = self.table.frame.origin.x;
    newFrame.size.width = self.table.frame.size.width;
    newFrame.size.height = 430;

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration 
                     animations:^{
                         self.table.frame = newFrame;

                     }];

    [self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification 
{

    keyboardAlreadyShow = NO;

}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATED**: Now I think I can narrow down the problem to this specific line

```
txtLatInteger.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...
```

Which txtLatInteger is an UITextView reside in the TableViewCell and will be updated every time another TextView in another TableViewCell changed. So if I comment out this line the TableView won't move. Any idea what happen?

**UPDATED2**: Seem like putting UITextView into UITableViewCell cause this bouncing problem. Change input field to UITextField solve this (sort of). But I have to sacrifice some specific behavior I need from UITextView. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like putting UITextView into UITableViewCell cause this bouncing problem. Change input field to UITextField solve this (sort of). But I have to sacrifice some specific behavior I need from UITextView. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a bouncing issue I have when my keyboard appears that is very similar to your code.  When my keyboard appears I animate the resizing of my UITableView in a similar way to your code.  I ported in your code to my keyBoardDidShow notification and I got nearly the same functionality as before.

I do not see your bouncing while typing issue so I'm theorizing your problem is not with your keyboardDidShow or keyboardDidHide notifications.  Do you have a program called Cinch installed?  I've seen it cause UITableViews to behave strangely in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, I didn't have Clinch app installed. Also, this happen both in simulator and on real device. :(